# i use two cursor for this. but i want to minimize it to one cursor

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @tab_name varchar(100)
declare @col_name varchar(100)
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)

declare cursor_table cursor
for
SELECT  TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES --where table_name!='tab'

open cursor_table 
fetch next from cursor_table into @tab_name
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    declare cursor_count cursor 
    for
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tab_name
    open cursor_count
    fetch next from cursor_count into @col_name
    while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    begin
    set @sqlquery='

     select '+''''+@tab_name+''''+','+''''+ @col_name+''''+',count('+@col_name+') as count from '+@tab_name+' where ISNULL('+@col_name+','''') !='''' '
    print @sqlquery         
    exec sp_executesql @sqlquery
    fetch next from cursor_count into @col_name
    End
    CLOSE cursor_count  
    DEALLOCATE cursor_count 
    print @tab_name
fetch next from cursor_table into @tab_name
end
CLOSE cursor_table  
DEALLOCATE cursor_table
```

Comment: Still waiting for the code format to be approved, but I'm pretty sure you can just join those two tables together. You should learn about joins before you learn about cursors

Comment: What is the point of this? The top 5 tables will not always be the same because you no order by on the outer cursor. Instead of limiting this to a single cursor you should eliminate both cursors as they are completely not needed. What you have here is a query for every column of the "first" 5 tables. What are you really trying to do because this makes no sense at all.

Comment: @SeanLange  Regardless of the *why*, it appears they want a `count` of all values in every column of the tables that is not `null` or blank?

Comment: @iamdave - Could be...but again. What is the point? Maybe this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it this way if I "needed" to get a count of all null values per column, per table.

This is very inefficient query and may take a while to execute as you are bound to perform multiple full table scans for all non-indexed fields. I would advise, for this exercise, that you limit it to a few tables.

```
SELECT CommandOrder=1,'DECLARE @TEMP TABLE(TableName NVARCHAR(100), ColumnName NVARCHAR(100), NullRecordCount INT)'
UNION
SELECT CommandOrder=3,
    'INSERT @TEMP SELECT '''+S.Name+'.'+T.Name+''','''+C.Name+''', COUNT(*) FROM '+S.Name+'.'+T.Name+' WHERE COALESCE('+C.Name+',NULL)=NULL' 
    FROM 
        SYS.Columns C 
        INNER JOIN SYS.Tables T ON C.object_id = T.object_id 
        INNER JOIN SYS.Schemas S ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
UNION
SELECT CommandOrder=4,'SELECT * FROM @TEMP T WHERE NullRecordCount > 0 ORDER BY TableName,ColumnName'
```

Answer (score 0):

> If it is a requirement to minimize it to one cursor at the very least, use this.

If you really have to use cursors, use FAST_FORWARD cursor option.

```
declare @tab_name varchar(100)
declare @col_name varchar(100)
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @mainTable TABLE(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
TABLE_NAME Varchar(500)
)

--GET TABLES data into main table 
INSERT INTO @mainTable 
SELECT  TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 

DECLARE @startTables INT = 1
DECLARE @finalTables INT = 0

SELECT @finalTables = MAX(Id) FROM @mainTable
-- Do a while loop over id
WHILE @startTables <= @finalTables
BEGIN 
    -- Get the table name
    SELECT @tab_name  =  TABLE_NAME  FROM @mainTable WHERE Id = @startTables
    -- Initialize cursor 
    declare cursor_count cursor 
    for
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tab_name
    open cursor_count
    fetch next from cursor_count into @col_name
    while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    begin
    set @sqlquery='select '+''''+@tab_name+''''+','+''''+ @col_name+''''+',count('+@col_name+') as count from '+@tab_name+' where ISNULL('+@col_name+','''') !='''' '
    print @sqlquery         
    exec sp_executesql @sqlquery
    fetch next from cursor_count into @col_name
    End
    CLOSE cursor_count  
    DEALLOCATE cursor_count 
    print @tab_name
 SET @startTables = @startTables + 1 
END
```

> To use no cursor at all, use this.

```
declare @tab_name varchar(100)
declare @col_name varchar(100)
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)

-- Table stores Id, table name, Query in one go.
DECLARE @secondaryTable TABLE(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
TABLE_NAME Varchar(500),
Query Varchar(8000)
)

INSERT INTO @secondaryTable 
SELECT a.TABLE_NAME, 'select '+''''+a.TABLE_NAME+''''+','+''''+ b.COLUMN_NAME+''''+',count('+b.COLUMN_NAME+') as count from '+a.TABLE_NAME+' where ISNULL('+b.COLUMN_NAME+','''') !='''' ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES a INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b ON a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
--SELECT * FROM @secondaryTable

DECLARE @startTables INT = 1
DECLARE @finalTables INT = 0

SELECT @finalTables = MAX(Id) FROM @secondaryTable
-- Loop through the table, get the table name and query. Execute the query.
WHILE @startTables <= @finalTables
BEGIN 
    SELECT @tab_name = TABLE_NAME, @sqlquery = Query FROM @secondaryTable WHERE Id = @startTables
    print @sqlquery
    exec sp_executesql @sqlquery
    print @tab_name
 SET @startTables = @startTables + 1 
END
```

Comment: reduce the cursor to avoid looping.again u use looping statement

Comment: Looping with while loop over a temporary variable table with a primary key is better than using cursor over database tables. Also, while loop is not being used to fetch data from anywhere. Its been used just to execute the statements prepared because your original question wanted to execute these SQL statements one by one in a loop. If I remove loop, how do you want these statements to execute?